# Not able to download a CSV file from a website

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

Maybe someone knows what's a problem with downloading from the site below... I run this code in Jupiter, and nothing happens.

```
import requests
import os

url  = 'http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/E0.csv'

response = requests.get(url)
with open(os.path.join("folder", "file"), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: That looks like an absolute path. Did you look for a `folder` folder at your computer's root folder?

Comment: I have launched your code and downloaded file without any issues. Only error can be is in path to file, check this..

Comment: Yep... If you provide absolute pat in folder and file its writing perfectly fine... whats error you are getting?

Comment: No, it doesn`t exist. Do you propose to use a folder like C://FTPDownloadLocation  ?

Comment: Error : "KeyboardInterrupt: "

Comment: Olvin, Kannan give an example of an absolute path please

Comment: @RV yea try with the absolute path. for example, replace `os.path.join("folder", "file")` with  `os.path.join("C://FTPDownloadLocation", "file.csv")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also tried this code and it works fine on my side, assuming `folder` and `file` were defined correctly. Alternatively, you can try using `pandas` which can read a CSV file from URL. So the code would become:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

url = '{Some CSV target}'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.to_csv('{absoulte path to CSV}', sep=',', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

It`s has started working only after declaring proxy. 
I`m practicing on my work laptop. Maybe the local net is blocking my requests.

I hope it can be helpful for someone.

Thanks to everyone for your help!

```
import requests
import os

os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'your proxy'
url  = 'http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/E0.csv'

response = requests.get(url)
with open(os.path.join("C://DownloadLocation", "file.csv"), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```